# how to define variable and do floating point arithmetic before print it out using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to do this

`grep E0 OSZICAR | tail -1 | awk -v var="$e0" '{vac = $5 - $var - 0.5 * 9.860; print vac}'`

$e0 is a bash variable defined before. Now we have the error message:

awk: fatal: attempt to access field -287

-287 is the interger part of $e0

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
grep E0 OSZICAR | tail -1 |
awk -v var="$e0" '{vac = ($5 - var - 0.5) * 9.860; print vac}'
```

Note use of `var` instead of `$var` inside awk and also parentheses around sub-expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` nor `tail` at all:

```
awk -v var="$e0" '/E0/{num=$5}END{print((num - var - 0.5) * 9.860)}' OSZICAR
```